# Inserting in a boost::interprocess::map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I have a following `boost::interprocess::map`:

```
using boost::interprocess;  
std::shared_ptr< map<uint32, managed_shared_memory*> > myMap;
```

I have a method() which inserts into this map:

```
void InsertInMap(uint32 i)
{
    myMap->insert( std::make_pair (i,                       // runtime error here
               new managed_shared_memory(create_only, "Test", 256)) );    

}
```

And in `main()`, I call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    InsertInMap(1);
}
```

This compiles fine.

But when I run my program, I get the following run-time error at the marked line (while insertion):

`memory access violation occurred at address ......, while attempting to read inaccessible data`

Am I missing something?

Comment: This has nothing to do with boost, interprocess or maps. Initialize your variables. And **don't `new` all the time** (this is not Java!)

Comment: Well, if you are pointing towards the `new` in `InsertInMap()` above, then that is required since I want a new memory for each `i` passed! As far as the error is concerned, I have realized the silly mistake I made!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

`myMap = boost::shared_ptr< map<uint32, managed_shared_memory*>  > (new map<uint32, managed_shared_memory*>  );`

to allocate the memory for the shared pointer before you use it to add to the map.  You are getting this error because myMap is conceptually the same as a null pointer until you allocate memory for it.

Comment: or.. not use dynamic allocation at all

Comment: Sorry for such a silly question! I wonder how I missed it. Effect of the festive season I guess ;)